# How to add custom control to ItemStyle.xsl for CQWP in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, custom-controls, cqwp

I would like to display breadcrumb for the pages rendered in CQWP. I have created the custom control for the breadcrumb but having trouble to use it in ItemStyle.xsl. If you know how to use custom control in ItemStyle.xsl, please share some info. Thank you!